# Firebase (Can't use .addValueEventListener with DatabaseReference)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to use the addValueEventListener with DatabaseReference to retrieve data from realtime database, I am using `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'`

this is my code

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button LED0_BTN, LED1_BTN, LED2_BTN, LED3_BTN;
int LED_On = 1;
int LED_Off = 0;

boolean LED0_Status = false;
boolean LED1_Status = false;
boolean LED2_Status = false;
boolean LED3_Status = false;

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference LED0_Ref = database.getReference().child("LED0_Status");
DatabaseReference LED1_Ref = database.getReference().child("LED1_Status");
DatabaseReference LED2_Ref = database.getReference().child("LED2_Status");
DatabaseReference LED3_Ref = database.getReference().child("LED3_Status");

ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

}

@Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

}
};
LED0_Ref.addValueEventLisnter(eventListener);
```

but it can't resolve .addValueEventListener

I can setValue of data but having hard time retrieving data

Comment: You're have a few typos in `Lisnter`: `addValueEventLisnter` should be `addValueEventListener`

Comment: I didn't notice cause I used it outside onCreate so it couldn't be resolved, hence no spell checking, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are not inside `onCreate` method of your activity.

Just go inside onCreate method and then just do:

```
LED0_Ref.addValueEventListener(eventListener);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked